How should i rethrow the firebase exception further?
I created app in flutter and authentication using FirebaseAuth where the UI and AuthApi files are separated when user press signup button it runs an async function which is in the other file. so if any error occurred then i want to access that firebase exception in UI file. here is code.

ui.dart file

try{
await authFunc();
}catch(e){
// 
}


authApi.dart

Future<void> authFunc() async{
try{
// FirebaseAuth functions
} on FirebaseException (e){
// i want to catch this exception on ui side async func
// rethrow didn't catch the error
}
}


maybe you should remove error handling in authApi.dart and just catch them in your ui file?

Just remove error handling in your api file and add on FirebaseException in your  ui file

that means remove the whole try catch block?

yes because you don't actually need it
